# In Google Sheets, How do I sumif(s) over a comma separated list in string?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In our schools, we have books of the same title by the same author but different ISBN #s. I am working on an inventory list so that we can scan the different ISBNs and then find out what is on hand for a title.

Here is my [working spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yP5lahSeWiTKo9H3y-th5DQ1Fdk7DX-GEwGc2LacZt4/edit#gid=0) demo. The live version will be separated (columns A-D by data that comes in on another sheet (possibly by Google Forms) and a separate sheet (F-J) that does all the math. For convenience / testing, they are all on one sheet.

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheet example]

Essentially, in column F, I would like to sum all the quantities in A where the ISBN's in C match any of the values of G and place it in F.

The formula I am using in F doesn't seem to completely work:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,arrayformula(split(G2,",")),A:A)
```

It captures the first match but ignores / doesn't loop over the rest. I have looked at Sumifs and Match and I cannot seem to get any closer with the syntax. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me solve this dilemma.

*Additionally, I know how to do this with a custom script but I need to avoid that as end users break things for one reason or another and I can't handle the debugging load the way this could possibly be deployed.*

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to take a look at this!

~Allan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in F2

```
=sum(query(A:D,"select A where C matches '"& textjoin("|",,split(G2,",")) &"' ",0))
```

[image]

Comment: Mike, thank you so much! I never would have gotten that! Your help is greatly appreciated! ~Allan

Answer (score 2):

delete everything in F2:F & J2:J and use F2:

```
=INDEX(IF(G2:G="",,MMULT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(G2:G, ","), {C:C, A:A}, 2, ), 0),
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(G2:G, ",")), 1, 1, ))))
```

[image]

in J2 use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="",,F2:F*I2:I))
```